# Receive JSON Array response from Java servlet in UTF-8 charset

Tags: java, json, ajax, servlets, utf-8

I am doing an ajax call to the java servlet. The servlet responds with a JSON Array with a charset set to UTF-8. However, once I get a response in the AJAX call, I get ??? characters in my strings. I went through a lot of testing and research and could not find a possible solution.

AJAX CALL:

```
                  $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {curTableName: curTableName,curTableID: curTableID},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: '../ShowProducts',
                    success: function(productInfo){ 
                       var noOfProducts = productInfo.length;
                        for(var i = 0; i < noOfProducts; i++)
                        {
                            product.push(productInfo[i].product.substr(0,25) + "...");
                            webshop.push(productInfo[i].webshop);
                            price.push(productInfo[i].price);
                            availability.push(productInfo[i].availability);
                            lastChecked.push(productInfo[i].lastChecked);
                            checkFreq.push(productInfo[i].checkFreq);
                            url.push(productInfo[i].url);
 DisplayProductInfo(product[i],webshop[i],price[i],availability[i],lastChecked[i],checkFreq[i],url[i]);
                        }
                    }   
                });
```

And my Java Servlet Response:

```
            response.setContentType("application/json");
            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            response.getWriter().write(jsonArr.toString());
```

Based on my own research the java servlet seems to be correct, and maybe there is an issue with the javascript. Anybody has any good ideas. All help is greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: Is your data UTF-8 encoded?

Comment: as shown in the Java servlet response, I set the characterencoding to UTF-8.

Comment: You set it but if the data loaded is not UTF-8 encoded, it won't work.

Comment: I will have a look into it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get it work. The problem resided in the fact that the JSON needed to be encoded in the servlet, and decoded in the javascript. Thank you - isah.

CODE CHANGES:

AJAX CALL:

```
     $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {curTableName: curTableName,curTableID: curTableID},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: '../ShowProducts',
                    success: function(productInfo){ 
                       var noOfProducts = productInfo.length;
                        for(var i = 0; i < noOfProducts; i++)
                        {
                            productInfo[i].product = decodeURIComponent(productInfo[i].product);
                            productInfo[i].product = productInfo[i].product.replace(/\+/g, ' ');
                            product.push(productInfo[i].product.substr(0,25) + "...");
                            webshop.push(productInfo[i].webshop);
                            price.push(productInfo[i].price);
                            availability.push(productInfo[i].availability);
                            lastChecked.push(productInfo[i].lastChecked);
                            checkFreq.push(productInfo[i].checkFreq);
                            url.push(productInfo[i].url);
 DisplayProductInfo(product[i],webshop[i],price[i],availability[i],lastChecked[i],checkFreq[i],url[i]);
                        }
                    }   
                });
```

JAVA SERVLET:

```
productSplit[0] = URLEncoder.encode( productSplit[0], "UTF-8");
```

Additional line has been added to Java servlet. Now the title gets encoded, and only after that it goes to the JSON object.